# How to fix TF246017 The Team foundation server could not connect to database

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfs-2012

I'm getting nothing but this error `TF246017` I'm not able to access TFS as admin or domain user

1. While accessing administration console, showing the error `TF246017`
2. Domain users getting `TF31001` where the server returns `TF246017`

TFS was working fine with SQL Server 2008. And now we have also installed SQL server 2012 in the same machine.( I believe it doesn't connected anyway to tfs server)

But, even after uninstalling SQL 2012, it displays the same error

In application tier/ database tier, getting error as `Error retrieving value`.

Unable to access `http://xxxxxxx:8080/tfs` displays same error `TF246017`

And also, im unable to locate the sql express database to take the backup.

**How** to resolve this issue?

Note : I'm using TFS 2012 and VS2010

Comment: not exactly the same but a similar issue http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tfssetup/archive/2012/05/23/tf246017-team-foundation-server-could-not-connect-to-the-database-failed-to-load-msxmlsql-dll-quot.aspx.

Comment: @JustTFS it might be a cause, since we intalled sql 2012 in the same machine as sql 2008 was working

Comment: You may just need to restart the SQL Server service.

Answer (score 4):

1. Login to windows server using the same windows credential user you used during SQL Server installation.
2. Verify or add the new windows user credential (assuming you are using different user credential to connect to TFS) to be part of sysadmin user group in SQL Server or ask your SQL Server DBA to add the user to sysadmin group.

   Note: This is required because for every new TFS Team project created, TFS presents 2 option empty database or new database. To create new database the TFS admin user have to be part of SQL server sysadmin group
3. If TFS 2012 was installed using the same windows credential, open the TFS Admin console and add or verify the user is listed in "administration Console Users" list.

If TFS Admin console reads "You do not have permission or not administrator" or something along this line, then you need to log out and log back using the correct windows credential used for installation or use one of the TFS admin user and then add the new user credential.

Recommendation: To avoid confusion I would recommend use the same user credential for SQL Server and TFS server. Ex: "domainname/tfs" is local admin to the server, sysadmin in SQL Server DB and also admin user to TFS server.

To make like simple start of by, adding the windows user (intended to use as TFS admin) as windows administration group. Then logout and log back using the TFS admin user to install SQL Server and TFS server.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue branch code in my version of TFS (Azure DevOps Premise). I tracked my issue down by looking at the event viewer on the local TFS server and found that I was that I was getting the following SQL error:

> DESCRIPTION: SQL Server Assertion: File: , line=951 Failed Assertion =
>   'IS_OFF (BUF_MINLOGGED, m_buf->bstat) || pageModifyType !=
>   PageModifyType_Contents || GetPagePtr ()->IsTextPage ()'. This error
>   may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the
>   statement, use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural
>   integrity, or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures
>   are not corrupted.

I found the first item in the [following answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/145087/113501) solved my issue.

I simply switched my main TFS database containing my collection to [FULL recovery mode](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3/sql-server-full-recovery-model/) and I was immediately able to proceed with my previously erroring task.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to your SQL instance via SQL Server Management Studio and check if any of the TFS databases are in a "Recovery Pending" state. If so, restart your SQL instance and the state should return to normal. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Just find out the Team foundation application under application pool. right click and go to advance setting set the identity using the credentials used for SQL Sever or TFS Admin and done ..you can now access the TFS as earlier.