# TFS246017- Unable to connect database

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2010

I am facing this problem after our VM is moved from one server to another server. Earlier in old server, I used to connect to TFS using DefaultCollection. I have all my files check in this DB.
Now when I am trying to connect to this collection, I get the following error.
Attached the image. Please help..where should I change the connection so that I can connect to this and restore my old TFS ..Team project..

I click on DefaultCollection in Team project collections in TFS Explore..I get the error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

While this error message can have multiple causes (invalid credentials, SQL Server not available/not started, etc.)

You could try to narrow down this issue by below possibilities:

> - Incorrect SQL Installation order especially if you are using Express    edition
> - Database In Recovery
> - Database Out-of-Sync – during migration to newer version of TFS
> - **Permission** of Service Account is not right
> - SQL Database not running or not reachable
> - TFS Proxy not reachable

More details please refer this [blog](http://www.ganshani.com/blog/2014/04/solved-tf246017-team-foundation-server-could-not-connect-to-the-database/) , also take a look at this similar error [How to fix TF246017 The Team foundation server could not connect to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26012081/how-to-fix-tf246017-the-team-foundation-server-could-not-connect-to-database)